# How to identify specific Ubuntu version?

Tags: versions

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Trusty_Tahr/) installed, but which?

1. /etc/issue states: Ubuntu **14.04.2** LTS
2. /proc/version reads: Linux version 3.16.0-77-generic (buildd@lgw01-09) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~**14.04.3**) ) #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 201
3. uname -a returns: Linux MSHV132 3.16.0-77-generic #99~**14.04.1**-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any idea?

Comment: And what about `lsb_release -a`?